# When to use unbeknown and unknown?

Tags: word-usage

Recently, I've seen the word *unbeknown*, which was new to me. Is there any difference between *unknown* and *unbeknown* in meaning and/or usage?

Comment: It should be _unbeknownst_, and it's a fragment of a fixed phrase: _`X` (be) unbeknownst to `P`_, or initially, _Unbeknownst to `P`, `X`_, where `P` is some person. Both mean that `P` doesn't know `X`.

Comment: 'That fact was unknown to me' vs 'That fact was unbeknown to me'. The second one is a bit old fashioned.

Comment: It appears that _unbeknown_ is a variant of _unbeknownst_, which isn't all that surprising. There are already two prefixes and one other suffix beside the archic _-st_, and that's hard to pronounce, so it'd be the first thing abandoned. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbeknownst

Comment: @JohnLawler I notice that the OED says of *unbeknownst*: **“The analogy on which the *-s* or *-st* has been added is not clear.”**  Me, I’m betting the analogy is on the *-st* that appears in prepositions like *against, amidst, amongst*, and not the one from the superlative degree. At least, that’s the excuse used for *whilst*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why (and for whom) does "unbeknown" become "unbeknownst"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107379/why-and-for-whom-does-unbeknown-become-unbeknownst)

Answer (score 1):

*Unbeknown* equals *unknown*; *unbeknown* is usually followed by *to*.

- It is unknown why she did this.
- It is unbeknown to me/us why she did this.

*Unknown* and *unbeknown* have very similar definitions and appear to be    interchangeable based on these definitions but sometimes one sounds    more correct than the other.

Also, *unbeknownst* is in *Webster’s Dictionary* as another way to say *unbeknown*.

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare the verbs *borrow* vs *lend* using the verbs *receive* and *supply*.

- *borrow* relates to accepting funds.
- *lend* relates to supplying funds.

The above comparison is unrelated to the words we are discussing except to illustrate the difference between receiver and supplier.

Let's compare the adjectives *known* vs *beknown*.

- *know* = the root word of the words being discussed here.
- *known*
  = past participle of *know* which relates to the party receiving attention
  = describing party supplying the presence for awareness.
- *beknown*
  relates to the party supplying the attention
  = describing party having/receiving the awareness of a presence.
- *beknow* = verb from which *beknown* is derivable.

Actually, *beknown* is archaic in use. It is an intermediate step I coined as a bridge to the next explanation.

Let's compare the adjectives/adverbs *unknown* vs *unbeknown*.

- *unknown*
  = negative of past participle of *know* which relates to the party receiving attention
  = party supplying the presence, but not emanating the awareness of its presence.
- *unbeknown*
  relates to the party supplying the attention, but not having/receiving the awareness of a presence

However, *unknown* has also taken up the meaning of *unbeknown*.
i.e., *unknown* can be used in place of *unbeknown*, but not conversely.

*Unbeknownst* is the more commonly used form of *unbeknown*.

*Unbeknownst*, *Unbeknown* are used if we wish to clearly communicate the restricted direction/indirection of flow of knowledge.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unbeknown
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beknow

Comment: This answer is unclear, and could benefit from some simplifications. First, working in standard grammatical terms, such as "subject" and "object" (rather than phrases like "relates to the party" and "describing the party") would be clearer. Second, "supplying" make sense with to borrow/lend, as they are about transferring something, but not so much with to know/beknow. More typical is to use "performing" or "doing" (an action).

Comment: Given that it's difficult to judge something that's unclear, this answer seems incorrect, both historically and currently. In my reading, this answer boils down to: "'unknown' applies to the object of knowing, and 'unbeknown' applies to the subject of knowing (that which performs the knowing)". This contradicts even the linked page defining "unbeknown".

Comment: ... Historically, ["beknown" is a synonym for "known"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbeknown#note-1-anchor), which falsifies any historical argument relying on a difference between the two. The whole confusion might result from the use of the past participle (e.g. "known") in passive voice & verbal adjectives, and their swapping of grammatical subject & object.